Stop execution of a python script as if it ran to the end
I want to stop the execution of a Python (3.12) script with a behaviour that is identical to the script running to completion in ideally all contexts, such as:

run with python script.py;
run with python -i script.py;
run inside Thonny's shell (or any other IDE's shell).

To simplify the discussion, let us assume a simple Python script as follows: (EDIT: This is just a simple example to play with; in reality, the exit function could be called from somewhere nested in a branch, a loop, or whatever.)
x = 1
print("HELLO")

magic_exit_function()

print("won't see this")
y = 1

I want a magic_exit_function that (a) ensures that HELLO is output, but won't see this isn't, (b) if run in interactive mode, ensures that the value of x can be inspected after the script ends, but not the value of y, and (c) doesn't produce any noise on stdout or stderr.
I have tried the following:

Use exit or quit or sys.exit. This works with python; with python -i it almost works (there is an ugly traceback with SystemExit, not satisfying (c)); with Thonny's shell it ends the subprocess and the value of x cannot be inspected afterwards (thus not satisfying (b)).

Raise a new kind of exception deriving from Exception. This produces noise, but at least I can inspect the value of x even in Thonny's shell.

Raise a new kind of exception deriving from Exception and set the sys.excepthook to ignore this kind of exception specifically. Works well with python and python -i, but still produces noise in Thonny's shell (Thonny seems to catch the exception and ignore sys.excepthook).

Try the same thing, but derive the exception from BaseException. There is no noise in Thonny, but the subprocess ends, and I cannot inspect the value of x afterwards.

Use sys.settrace and the ability to set f_lineno of the current frame. This almost works (in all tested scenarios), but the problem is that I cannot use this to jump to the end of the current module; I can only jump to the last line of the module, and this last line is always executed. This breaks (b), because the y = 1 line is executed.


Are there any other possibilities without changing the script itself (apart from the magic_exit_function)?
The implementation of the various attempts at magic_exit_function follow:
def magic_exit_function1():
    import sys
    sys.exit()  # or exit() or quit() or raise SystemExit()


def magic_exit_function2():
    class MyExit(Exception):
        pass

    raise MyExit()


def magic_exit_function3():
    import sys

    class MyExit(Exception):
        pass

    def hook(exc_type, exc, tb):
        if exc_type is MyExit:
            return None
        return sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc, tb)

    sys.excepthook = hook
    raise MyExit()


def magic_exit_function4():
    import sys

    class MyExit(BaseException):
        pass

    def hook(exc_type, exc, tb):
        if exc_type is MyExit:
            return None
        return sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc, tb)

    sys.excepthook = hook
    raise MyExit()


def magic_exit_function5():
    import sys
    import inspect

    def trace(frame, event, arg):
        if event != 'line':
            return trace

        frame.f_lineno = last_line
        return trace

    sys.settrace(lambda *args, **kwargs: None)
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    _, _, last_line = list(frame.f_code.co_lines())[-1]
    frame.f_trace = trace


So why not just remove print("won't see this"); y = 1 from the script? Do you want magic_exit_function() to run conditionally? I'm just asking to make sure this isn't an XY problem; you might want to add some context about what you're trying to do.

Yes, I want the magic_exit_function to run conditionally.

As for the XY problem... Obviously, I am trying to do something more complicated than this. I have just tried to isolate the issue to a very simple, understandable example.

Have you tried just setting sys.excepthook to a no-op function then raise SystemExit(0)? That seems to work for me in all the IDEs I've tested. Not sure about Thonny because I don't know how you're running the script with Thonny.

This is the same as my attempt no. 4. The subprocess in Thonny ends, and there is no way to inspect the value of the variables in the shell. I am running it with the Run button (which is the same as writing %Run myscript.py in Thonny's shell).
